# Calling WebRequest with Endpoint generate 591

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Hello I am trying to call a webservice that is running on my machine and when I call it without the endpoint everything run fine, when I add the endpoint give me an error 591 returned by the webserver, this is my code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8111/fiscal");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Host = "localhost:8111";

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData));
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }


        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseValue = string.Empty;

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // grab the response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(responseValue);
        }
```

Comment: What are you calling the "End Point"?  Don't see it in the code.

Comment: Yes, the "/fiscal".

Comment: The folder "fiscal/ needs to be shared and have the correct credentials.  You can check with a Windows Explorer and make sure the folder can be see using in the address box address : \\localhost

Comment: When I try to acccess to the fiscal folder by the browser execute the call.

Comment: Which type browser?  You may need to add a the User-Agent Header to the request indicating the type of browser.  The other possibility is the request is using http 1.1 which is chunk mode that doesn't work with Net Library.  Chunk requires a "next chunk" message to be send after each chunk and net library doesn't allow the next chunk to be sent and you get a timeout.  Solution is to add to request HTTP Version 1.0 which is stream mode.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to compare first request with browser and then your app.